# Шелуха от семечек и скорлупка и кожура

Tags: семантика

Можно ли шелуху от семечек называть скорлупкой или кожурой?

Answer (score 3):

скорлупа
1) Твёрдая природная оболочка чего-либо. || Подходит, так как в семечках оболочка твёрдая. Раз семечки маленькие, то *скорлупка*.
*Яичная скорлупа.

Скорлупа ореха.*

*Кожура* употребляется при мягкой оболочке (по аналогии с кожей):
*Очистить апельсин от кожуры.

Картофельная кожура.

Отвар луковой кожуры.*

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, можно.

Значение слова Шелуха по Ефремовой:

> **Шелуха - 1. Кожица**, счищенная с овощей, плодов, скорлупа и т.п.
>   2. перен. То, что является лишь внешней оболочкой; нечто лишнее, ненужное.

Значение слова Шелуха по Ожегову:

> Шелуха.  Оболочка некоторых плодов, овощей
>
> Шелуха. Нечто внешнее, ненужное, наносное
>
> Шелуха. Кожура семян

http://tolkslovar.ru/sh883.html

> Значение слова Кожура по словарю Ушакова: КОЖУРА, кожуры, мн. нет, ж.
>   1. Плотная кожа плодов. Кожура кокосовых орехов. Кожура апельсина. Снять кожуру с банана.

Значение слова Кожура по Ефремовой:

> **Кожура - Внешняя оболочка плода, семени.**

Значение слова Кожура по Ожегову:

> Кожура - Наружный покров, оболочка плодов, семян

Здесь нет разделения на мягкую и твёрдую оболочку. Это у нас сыгрывает частотность употребления в быту слова шелуха, скорлупками и кожурой как-то не называют оболочку семечек, но если подумать, это и есть кожица, и у нежареных семечек она как раз мягкая, а высыхает - становится твёрдой. Так что вполне корректные синонимы (для семечек) - шелуха, кожица, скорлупка.

Comment: Думаю, что _разделение_ есть. Например, у грецкого ореха, миндаля и пр. есть кожура поверх скорлупы, и их нужно различать по наименованию.

Comment: Вы уверены, что можете сказать про твёрдую оболочку "*снять кожуру с ореха*"? Словари не диктуют нормы, а отражают существующее употребление слов. Между любыми словами есть разница. И её необходимо найти.

Comment: Собственными руками снимал грецкий орех с дерева, а  с его скорлупы - кожуру. Про снятие "твёрдой оболочки" я не говорил. https://img.7dach.ru/image/600/17/79/12/2018/01/23/5ee705.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Слово **шелуха** употребляется *собирательно* по отношению к *массе*, в которой мелкие *скорлупки* или парные *чешуйки* (так их именуют специалисты по подсолнечнику, см. напр. википедию) неразличимы. В аспекте малого количества очисток или при описании частей отдельных семечек "шелуха" заменяется на одно из упомянутых слов (в бытовом контексте лучше **скорлупки**). Кожура - обычно мягкая наружная оболочка поверх плода (яблоко) или семени (скорлупы грецкого ореха, миндаля).